# Add custom route in Loopback over nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, loopbackjs

I am attempting to add a custom middleware route to an existing Loopback application, but seeing strange errors using my local domain mapping, but everything works fine on localhost:3000.

My setup is using nginx as a proxy server using

```
location /api {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

I have added the example server/boot/aroutes.js file from the [Add a custom Express Route](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+custom+Express+route) docs page:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  // Install a "/ping" route that returns "pong"
  app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.send('pong');
  });
}
```

My server/boot looks like this, so aroutes.js is alphabetically first:

```
server/boot/
  aroutes.js
  authentication.js
  rest-api.js
```

My app and the /api same domain proxy work as intended for the app when called by AngularJS, but I can't seem to get a custom Express route to work when called via https://domain.com/api/ping, *but it works fine when I use http://localhost:3000/ping.*

Using `http://localhost:3000/ping` I get

[image]

But using the full mock domain over the nginx ssl proxy, it does not take the same route:

[image]

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 404,
    "message": "There is no method to handle GET /ping",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "stack": "Error: There is no method to handle GET /ping
    at restUrlNotFound (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/rest-adapter.js:332:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at jsonParser (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:96:40)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /Users/notbrain/src/proteus/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7"
  }
}
```

Is this expected behavior? How can I get the two to be equivalent? Seems like two issues here

1. nginx proxy_pass is interfering with loopback routing
2. my custom route is not registered with loopback when nginx interferes

**UPDATE 6/24**: More explicit nginx config used here:

```
http {

  # ...snip logging etc... #

  upstream api {
    # loopback api on port 3000
    server localhost:3000;
  }

  upstream app {
    # browser-sync frontend for dev on port 3001
    server localhost:3001;
  }

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
  }

  server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  dev.app.proteus.com;

    ssl_certificate      ssl/dev.app.proteus.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ssl/dev.app.proteus.com.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    # ----- PFS ----- #
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";

    location / {
      # proxy_pass to connect server spawned by gulp browserSync ------------
      proxy_pass http://app;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://api;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be a Loopback specific issue, but more related to Nginx and how its setup.  To verify this, try creating a simple Hello World app in Node.js to see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `upstream` in nginx config.

In your loopback config for that environment, change `host` parameter to server name. Then in your nginx config upstream, instead of `localhost:{port}`, change to the same server name.

For example in `server/config.test.js` for test environment (`export NODE_ENV=test` before starting server), you could override the default host:

```
module.exports = {
    host: "app3",
    ...
}
```

Then in your `etc/nginx/conf.d/{app-name}.conf` file (good to create one per app), you can have something like this:

```
upstream my-app {
    server app3:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-server-domain.com;

    # custom handlers for internal apps
    # add stuff as needed below
    #
    location ^~ / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://my-app;
    }
}
```

Now you could always change the `location` param to not be global and just use `/api` but same handling.  The trick is the Loopback config `host` param must match the host declared in your upstream of nginx config.

Comment: In my experience this is Loopback specific and has something to do with the "hosts" params in config.  Also with this, the `/explorer` doesn't seem to work and URL changes from http://localhost:3000/v1/rest/endpoint to http://app3/v1/rest/endpoint instead of expected http://your-server-domain.com/v1/rest/endpoint so there is still some config I haven't found myself to solve that but will soon - ran into same issue.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I figured out how to fix the `/explorer` URL issue too by adding some additional proxy configs to the location block in nginx config.  Updated example above.

Comment: Thanks @Mike S. I was already using the `upstream` syntax in nginx, just made it simpler for the post. I will see if adding a host config name will help. Luckily I am only using these server side templates for dev-time previewing of HTML email instead of something that is going to production.